# How to deduct time in 24 hours using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

My use case is very simple, How do i deduct the current time in 24 hours. Technically it is like snapchat, 24 hours from now it will dissapear, hence why I need to deduct the time.

```
11:50 PM - 10 Jan 2017
```

I want to deduct the current time to the next 24 hours time only

```
(10:50 PM - 11 Jan 2017) - (11:50 PM 10 Jan 2017) = 1 hour left
```

How would I do such thing in Moment.js ?

Comment: Your question is somewhat vague. Could you add some more examples and include the code you tried?

Comment: @pzp I added more explanation

Answer (score 3):

You can add `-24` hours. See [moment.add](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)

```
moment(date).add(-24, 'hours');
```

And to display relative time you can use [moment.fromNow](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)

Comment: instead of `.add(-24)`, you can `.subtract(24)`

Comment: in 2021 you can use substract `moment(this.currentDate).subtract(24, 'hours')` just for people now

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should use moment.js take a look here

[Moment from method](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/)

In fact you can deduct time passed between to dates like this

```
var start = moment("10:50 PM - 11 Jan 2017");
var end = moment("11:50 PM 10 Jan 2017");
start.from(end); // "1 hour"
```

Comment: This does not answer the asker's question. OP said they were already using Moment.js and was asking *how* they could do some specific thing with it, not *if* they should be using it.

Comment: Sorry didn't catch the thing. So you want to compare only the time between the to dates?

Answer (score 1):

I think this would help you :

//valid formats to subtract

```
moment().subtract(String, Number);
moment().subtract(Number, String); // 2.0.0
moment().subtract(String, String); // 2.7.0
moment().subtract(Duration); // 1.6.0
moment().subtract(Object);
```

//easy examples

```
var myString = "03:15:00",
    myStringParts = myString.split(':'),
    hourDelta: +myStringParts[0],
    minuteDelta: +myStringParts[1];


date.subtract({ hours: hourDelta, minutes: minuteDelta});
date.toString()
```

Comment: thank you for helping, but seems like your code doesn't work. Im confused.

Comment: where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Read http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/ for documentation on moment js parse.

This just might work. It did work in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Bjolja/p2bcm2oa/

```
var dt = moment("12:15 AM", ["h:mm A"]).format("HH:mm");
```